# Array as get parameter in Struts 2

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, http-get

I have an action like below

```
public class CompareAction {

    private Long[] pids;

    public Long[] getPids() {
        return pids;
    }

    public void setPids(Long[] pids) {
        this.pids = pids;
    }

    public String displayComparison() {
        for (Long pid : pids) {
            System.out.println("pid = " + pid);
            System.out.println();
        }
        return "success";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send an array by typing following url in the addressbar `http://localhost:8080/sm-shop/compare?pids=12,23,34`. The output I want is

```
pid = 12

pid = 23

pid = 34
```

But what I'm getting is

```
pid = 122334
```

I tried googling but couldn't find how to do this. Please help me figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Try `http://localhost:8080/sm-shop/compare?pids[]=12&pids[]=23&pids[]=34` as the URL?

Comment: Or add a custom converter...

Comment: how to add custom converter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass parameter `pids` multiple times:

```
http://localhost:8080/sm-shop/compare?pids=12&pids=23&pids=34
```

If you declared your `pids` property as array Struts2 will automatically map multiple parameters to array.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep this(`http://localhost:8080/sm-shop/compare?pids=12,23,34`) url format either you have to add a custom converter or you can make pids a String in your action and parse the array by splitting it at commas.