# javascript array to struts2 list

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have textfields in my JSP. I make them filled by the user, collects it's values and send it to action class as list of strings.

My js file:

```
var thresholdParameters = [];
    $('[id^="thresholdParameter_"]').each(function(i, value) {

        thresholdParameters[i++] = $(this).val();

    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/gma/setDefaultParametersConfigureTspThreshold.action?&thresholdParameters='+thresholdParameters
```

In my action class I get it as a List of Strings:

```
private List<String> thresholdParameters;
```

However, after getting thresholdParameters inside action class  when i call a bean method and send thresholdParameters to a bean method, an exception is thrown 
`java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException` caused by

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter
```

STACKTRACE:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
14:22:36,658 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy928.setThresholdParameters(Unknown Source)
14:22:36,658 ERROR [STDERR]     at cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts.ConfigureTspThresholdAction.setDefaultParameters(ConfigureTspThresholdAction.java:223)
14:22:36,658 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:22:36,659 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
14:22:36,659 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:22:36,659 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
14:22:36,659 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
14:22:36,659 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
14:22:36,660 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
14:22:36,660 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
14:22:36,660 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
14:22:36,660 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,660 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
14:22:36,660 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
14:22:36,661 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
14:22:36,661 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,661 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
14:22:36,661 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,661 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
14:22:36,661 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
14:22:36,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
14:22:36,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
14:22:36,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
14:22:36,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,663 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
14:22:36,663 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,663 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
14:22:36,663 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,663 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
14:22:36,663 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,664 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
14:22:36,664 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,664 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
14:22:36,664 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,664 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
14:22:36,665 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,665 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
14:22:36,665 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,665 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
14:22:36,665 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
14:22:36,665 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,666 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
14:22:36,666 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,666 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
14:22:36,666 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,666 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
14:22:36,666 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,667 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
14:22:36,667 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
14:22:36,667 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
14:22:36,667 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
14:22:36,667 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
14:22:36,667 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
14:22:36,668 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
14:22:36,668 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
14:22:36,668 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
14:22:36,668 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
14:22:36,668 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
14:22:36,669 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
14:22:36,669 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
14:22:36,669 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
14:22:36,669 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
14:22:36,669 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
14:22:36,669 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
14:22:36,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
14:22:36,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
14:22:36,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
14:22:36,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
14:22:36,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
14:22:36,670 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
14:22:36,671 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
14:22:36,671 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
14:22:36,671 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
14:22:36,671 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter
14:22:36,671 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1181)
14:22:36,671 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1541)
14:22:36,672 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1506)
14:22:36,672 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
14:22:36,672 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
14:22:36,672 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
14:22:36,672 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1171)
14:22:36,673 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
14:22:36,673 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.<init>(MarshalledObject.java:118)
14:22:36,673 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.writeExternal(MethodInvocation.java:373)
14:22:36,673 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.invocation.StatefulRemoteInvocation.writeExternal(StatefulRemoteInvocation.java:78)
14:22:36,673 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.serial.persister.ExternalizePersister.writeData(ExternalizePersister.java:58)
14:22:36,673 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
14:22:36,674 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:390)
14:22:36,674 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.serial.io.MarshalledObjectForLocalCalls.<init>(MarshalledObjectForLocalCalls.java:38)
14:22:36,674 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invokeLocal(IsLocalInterceptor.java:79)
14:22:36,674 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:72)
14:22:36,674 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
14:22:36,674 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
14:22:36,675 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy811.invoke(Unknown Source)
14:22:36,675 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
14:22:36,675 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
14:22:36,675 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 75 more
```

ConfigureTspThreshols:

```
public String setDefaultParameters(){

        try{
            slsCommonRemote = this.getSlsCommonRemote();
            System.out.println("hello in constructor");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {   
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("[AnalysisStatisticsAction]:In catch Inside Constructor!!");
        }
        System.out.println("//////////ThresholdPara" + thresholdParameters);

        try{
            slsCommonRemote.setThresholdParameters(circleId, tspId, flag, list);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("CAUSE*********  " + e.getCause()+ "\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return DISPLAY;
    }
```

EJB:

```
public class SlsCommonBean implements SlsCommonRemote, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "gmaEM")
    EntityManager em;

        public void setThresholdParameters (String circleId, String tspId, String flag, List<String> parameters) {


            System.out.println("[SlsCommonBean]: setThresholdParameters::::" + parameters);
            GmaThreshold newEntity = new GmaThreshold();

            newEntity.setId (new GmaThresholdPK (Long.valueOf(circleId).longValue(), Long.valueOf(tspId).longValue(), flag) );

            newEntity.setDistinctBnumberRatio("80:1");

            newEntity.setMinNumberOc (new BigDecimal (parameters.get(0)) );
            newEntity.setMinDurationOc (new BigDecimal (parameters.get(1)) );
            newEntity.setMaxNumberIc (new BigDecimal (parameters.get(2)) );
            newEntity.setMaxDurationIc (new BigDecimal (parameters.get(3)) );
            newEntity.setMaxNumberCellId (new BigDecimal (parameters.get(4)) );
            newEntity.setDistinctBnumberRatio (parameters.get(5) );
            newEntity.setMinPercentDistinctBnumber (new BigDecimal (parameters.get(6)) );

            newEntity = em.merge(newEntity);
    }
}
```

Entity: GmaThreshold:

```
public class GmaThreshold implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GmaThreshold(long circleId, long tspId, int minNumberOc, int minDurationOc ,int maxNumberIc,
            int maxDurationIc, int maxNumberCellId,String distinctBnumberRatio, int minPercentDistinctBnumber, String flag) 
    {
        this.minNumberOc = new BigDecimal(minNumberOc);
        this.id = new GmaThresholdPK(circleId,tspId,flag); // for primary keys
        this.minDurationOc = new BigDecimal(minDurationOc);
        this.maxNumberIc = new BigDecimal(maxNumberIc);
        this.maxDurationIc = new BigDecimal(maxDurationIc);
        this.maxNumberCellId = new BigDecimal(maxNumberCellId);
        this.distinctBnumberRatio = distinctBnumberRatio;
        this.minPercentDistinctBnumber = new BigDecimal(minPercentDistinctBnumber);
        //this.timeTaken=new BigDecimal(timeTaken); // needed for conversion of bigdecimal to long
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private GmaThresholdPK id;

    @Column(name="DISTINCT_BNUMBER_RATIO")
    private String distinctBnumberRatio;

    @Column(name="MAX_DURATION_IC")
    private BigDecimal maxDurationIc;

    @Column(name="MAX_NUMBER_CELL_ID")
    private BigDecimal maxNumberCellId;

    @Column(name="MAX_NUMBER_IC")
    private BigDecimal maxNumberIc;

    @Column(name="MIN_DURATION_OC")
    private BigDecimal minDurationOc;

    @Column(name="MIN_NUMBER_OC")
    private BigDecimal minNumberOc;

    @Column(name="MIN_PERCENT_DISTINCT_BNUMBER")
    private BigDecimal minPercentDistinctBnumber;

    public GmaThreshold() {
    }

    public GmaThresholdPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(GmaThresholdPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDistinctBnumberRatio() {
        return this.distinctBnumberRatio;
    }

    public void setDistinctBnumberRatio(String distinctBnumberRatio) {
        this.distinctBnumberRatio = distinctBnumberRatio;
    }

    public BigDecimal getMaxDurationIc() {
        return this.maxDurationIc;
    }

    public void setMaxDurationIc(BigDecimal maxDurationIc) {
        this.maxDurationIc = maxDurationIc;
    }

    public BigDecimal getMaxNumberCellId() {
        return this.maxNumberCellId;
    }

    public void setMaxNumberCellId(BigDecimal maxNumberCellId) {
        this.maxNumberCellId = maxNumberCellId;
    }

    public BigDecimal getMaxNumberIc() {
        return this.maxNumberIc;
    }

    public void setMaxNumberIc(BigDecimal maxNumberIc) {
        this.maxNumberIc = maxNumberIc;
    }

    public BigDecimal getMinDurationOc() {
        return this.minDurationOc;
    }

    public void setMinDurationOc(BigDecimal minDurationOc) {
        this.minDurationOc = minDurationOc;
    }

    public BigDecimal getMinNumberOc() {
        return this.minNumberOc;
    }

    public void setMinNumberOc(BigDecimal minNumberOc) {
        this.minNumberOc = minNumberOc;
    }

    public BigDecimal getMinPercentDistinctBnumber() {
        return this.minPercentDistinctBnumber;
    }

    public void setMinPercentDistinctBnumber(BigDecimal minPercentDistinctBnumber) {
        this.minPercentDistinctBnumber = minPercentDistinctBnumber;
    }

}
```

I **EDITED** my JS as below to properly convert js array to List: 
JS:

```
$('[id^="thresholdParameter_"]').each(function(i, value) {

        //thresholdParameters[i++] = $(this).val();
        //alert(typeof(thresholdParameters[i-1]));
        allVals += "thresholdParameters="+$(this).val()+"&";    
    });
    if(allVals.length>0){
        allVals = allVals.substring(0,allVals.length-1); //remove last '&'
    }  
    alert(allVals);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/gma/setDefaultParametersConfigureTspThreshold.action?circleId='+circleId+'&tspId='+tspId+'&flag='+flag+'&'+allVals,
```

and in my Action class if I send the thresholdParameters list as it is it gives the exception however if i locally create a new list from the returned list the code works. In action clas: 
Edited Acttion class:

```
public String setDefaultParameters(){
            System.out.println("[setDeafultParameters]: CircleID**************" + circleId+ "\nTSPID*****"+tspId);

            try{
                slsCommonRemote = this.getSlsCommonRemote();
                System.out.println("hello in constructor");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {   
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("[AnalysisStatisticsAction]:In catch Inside Constructor!!");
            }
            //thresholdParameters = new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.println("//////////ThresholdPara" + thresholdParameters);

List<String> list = new ArrayList();

            for (String serviceAreaId : thresholdParameters) {

                list.add(serviceAreaId);

            }

            try{
                slsCommonRemote.setThresholdParameters(circleId, tspId, flag, list);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("CAUSE*********  " + e.getCause()+ "\n");
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return DISPLAY;
        }
```

After the above edits in JS and ACtion class it works. But putting it in a local list and sending I feel is just a HACK. Why is it not working otherwise.??
I want to know is this because there is some conversion problem from array to java list??
Plese help.

Comment: @RomanC:  I have posted the stracktrace

Comment: Post `ConfigureTspThresholdAction::setDefaultParameters`.

Comment: Try to make the ejb implement `Serializable`.

Comment: @RomanC: I made it serializable. But still the exception persists

Comment: Post the EJB code, type of parameters passed to `setThresholdParameters`, also deployment infrastructure.

Comment: Entities should implement serializable.

Comment: @RomanC: My entity GmaThreshold implements Serializable

Comment: You didn't handle `null` values in the code, it should throw `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: I will handle null values, but how to handle the present exception?

Comment: @RomanC: Please look at the edits in the question

Comment: @RomanC: JS and Action edits

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19385476/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM: As done in my JS file edit, i succesfully converted it into List<String>. Still the exception persits.