# Pass an array via AJAX call and struts2 to a java class

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, struts2

**Javascript-AJAX call**

```
function assignTask(){
var formdata = "xyz";
var taskList = [];
$.each($("input[name='taskname']:checked"), function(){            
taskList.push($(this).val());
});
$.ajax({
type: "post",
data: {taskList:taskList},
url: "AssignTask" ,
traditional: true,
success: function (data)
{
 ........}
});
}
```

Now ***var taskList*** is storing array successfully. Since i have checked that already.
The problem happens inside the AJAX function while sending the ***array taskList***.

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources"/>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" >
<action name="AssignTask" class="dto.Task" method="assignTasks">
<result name="success">jsp/TaskList.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**dto.Task java class** with method **assignTasks()**

```
public class Task extends ActionSupport {
private ArrayList<Task> taskList;
public ArrayList<Task> getTaskList() {
return taskList;}
public void setTaskList(ArrayList<Task> taskList) {
this.taskList = taskList;
}
public String assignTasks() {
System.out.println("Inside assign tasks..."+ taskList.size());
String result = "success";
return result;
}
}
```

When I am running the application in Netbeans, glassfish console is showing me this error:

```
Warning:   Could not find action or result
No result defined for action dto.Task and result input
at at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation......
......
```

Google Chrome console is showing me this error:

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8080/EmployeeManagement/AssignTask 404 
(No result defined for action dto.Task and result input)
```

So my program's control is not going inside the function ***assignTasks()*** and of course there is a problem in passing array from AJAX function to the ***dto.Task*** java class via **struts2** framework.

Please help me solve it.
﻿

​

Comment: Put an `input` result and use Struts tags to see error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array as get parameter in Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385476/array-as-get-parameter-in-struts-2)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding namespace attribute as below?

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
...
</package>
```